# hide <tr> with style display:none does not work

Tags: html

I want to hide `<tr>` , when i do below for `<td>` it works but for `<tr>` it does not, how i can hide `<tr>`?

```
<td style="display:none">Eve</td> -- works

<tr style='display:none'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HighlightedTextSearch")%>
                         </tr> -- does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:none` works fine on a table row:

```html
<table>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>This will not be visible</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your problem is that you're not wrapping the content in a `<td>` so it's getting bumped outside the table altogether, and therefore is not being controlled by the `tr`'s styling:

```css
table {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<table>
<tr style="display:none">
This is invalid HTML, because it's not inside a table cell.
Note that this sentence is displayed *before* the table rather than inside it.
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The display none on the tr does work. See the row 2 in the demo below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none">row 1</td>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style='display:none'>
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>row 3</td>
    <td>row 3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```